# Possible definition of the cotangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, definition, smooth-manifolds, co-tangent-space

This definition is inspired by the book mentioned in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4253708/contangent-space-as-a-jet-space-inconsistency-renteln). As it turns out later it is identical to that in question mentioned in the comment by Paul Frost.

The tangent space at $p \in M$ can be defined as the space of derivations on $C^\infty(M)$. I thought that the space of functions $C^\infty(M)$, which is a very large jungle of smooth functions, is actually redundant, to charaterise these special maps (derivations) by their action on them. So I wanted to reduce it bya quotient. First I have to prove that if the derivative of a smooth function at $p \in U \subset M$ vanishes in a some coordinates, it vanishes in all other compatible coordinates. Indeed, if $p \in U$ and $(U,\phi),(U,\psi)$ are any compatible charts, then for all $f \in C^\infty(M)$ we have, if
$$
\hat f = f \circ \phi^{-1}:\phi(U) \to \mathbb R, \quad D\hat f_{\phi(p)} = 0
$$
then
$$
\tilde f = f \circ \psi^{-1} = \hat f\circ \phi\circ\psi^{-1}:\psi(U) \to \mathbb R,\quad  D\tilde f_{\psi(p)} = (D\hat f_{\phi(p)})\circ (D (\phi\circ\psi^{-1})_{\psi(p)}) = 0
$$
The subset $W_p(M) \subset C^\infty(M)$ of functions with vanishing derivative is well defined and is a subspace, so one may take the quotient
$$
T_p^*M := C^\infty(M)/W_p(M)
$$
The elements are equivalence classes of functions, each class is a set of functions with common (first) derivative. The derivative itself as a map $D(f\circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)} \in \mathbb R^{m*}$ will depend on the coordinate map $\phi$. Since these classes are distinguished from each other by the first derivative (in some coordinates) then $\dim T_p^*M = \dim \mathbb R^{m*} = m$, as expected, since $\mathbb R^{m*}$ is the set of all such linear maps $D(f\circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}$. One has still to prove that under coordinate change the classes are the preserved, which should be an easy part.

Choosing some coordinate map, the coordinate function $x^i:U \to \mathbb R$, or rather their classes $[x^i]$, constitute a basis for $T_p^*M$. Then a tangent vector $v_p$ is the map
$$
v_p: [f] \mapsto  D(f\circ \phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)}(v^\phi), \quad v^\phi \in \mathbb R^m
$$

Could anyone check if every thing above is consistent ?

---

### Update

The Leibniz property emerges from this definition of the tangent vector as a consequence of the old product rule and since
$$
(fg)\circ \phi^{-1} = (f\circ \phi^{-1})(g\circ \phi^{-1}).
$$
Also the independence of the number $v_p([f])$ of the coordinate map $\phi$ gives the transformation rule
$$
v^\phi \mapsto v^\psi = (D (\psi\circ\phi^{-1})_{\phi(p)})(v^\phi).
$$

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4230215) may be relevant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reference, almost identical if not the same definition